# Unable to retrieve rows in MYSQL where Password() has been used

Tags: mysql

I am using PASSWORD() to hash my passwords. I understand that this is not a preferred method and may not be very secure but i am still using it for some application that hardly needs any security. So, my insert statements look like:

```
INSERT into AUTH(id,pass) VALUES ('myUserName', PASSWORD('myPass'));
```

I verified that myPass is hashed now.

Now i am trying to get a count of rows where the password is set to myPass. I have tried using the following query but i continue to get 0 count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUTH where pass=PASSWORD('myPass');
```

Any recommendations please?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with those exact queries. So: either the variables are not _exactly_ the same (look out for whitespace), or the insert fails (double id perhaps?).

Comment: Also the mysql docs suggest not using password for applications

Comment: I have verified that insert works. When you say that you can't reproduce the problem, does it mean that you are getting correct count? i.e. a non-zero count

Comment: @Newcoder: have you verified that the entire password string is being stored, and is not being truncated?

Comment: Note that, as documented: "The [`PASSWORD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) function is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should *not* use it in your own applications. For that purpose, consider [`MD5()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5) or [`SHA2()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2) instead."

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the `pass` column in the `AUTH` table is at least 41 characters, or whatever value is returned from:

```
SELECT LENGTH(PASSWORD('foo'))
LENGTH(PASSWORD('foo'))  
-------------------------
                       41
```

This test case demonstrates what happens when `pass` column in `authbad` table is not big enough to hold entire password string:

```
 CREATE TABLE auth (id VARCHAR(32), pass VARCHAR(41));  // pass column matches length
 INSERT INTO auth VALUES ('abc',PASSWORD('abc'));

 CREATE TABLE authbad (id VARCHAR(32), pass VARCHAR(32));  // pass column too short
 INSERT INTO authbad VALUES ('abc',PASSWORD('abc'));

 SELECT COUNT(1) FROM auth WHERE pass=PASSWORD('abc');
 COUNT(1)  
 ----------
          1

 SELECT COUNT(1) FROM authbad WHERE pass=PASSWORD('abc');
 COUNT(1)  
 ----------
          0
```

---

Another (less likely) issue is that a characterset conversion is taking place, either on the INSERT or on the SELECT which is not occurring in the other. Given that the password returns an asterisk and  hex digits (in upper case), I don't really see how that should be an issue though.

Comment: Verified that the above solution works. pass was defined with 32 characters. Changed to 41 and now it works. Thanks much for your help.

Comment: If you found my answer solved your issue, you can "accept" the answer. Some are reluctant to answer new questions from members who do not accept answers.